# Auto_route unable to use the generated file : no name parameter with the name 'reportsRouteUpdateToEngine'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i'm trying auto_route but i don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Here is my router.dart :

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    // initial route is named "/"
    MaterialRoute(page: HomeView, initial: true),
    MaterialRoute(page: StartupView),
  ],
)
class $Router {}
```

And here is my main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder(
        router: Router(),
        builder: (context, extendedNav) => Theme(
          data: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
          child: extendedNav,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i've run

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Then when i run myApp and then i get this error :

```
Error: No named parameter with the name 'reportsRouteUpdateToEngine'.
      reportsRouteUpdateToEngine: true,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I also tried without their extendedNav, just like this :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: Router(),
    );
  }
}
```

Still doesn't work.
Any help ?

Comment: I downgrade to an oldest version of auto_route and it works, but i don't understand why i can't make it with the newest version.

Answer (score 2):

The `0.6.9` version seems to work only with the latest flutter version (1.22).
My flutter version was outdated, i upgraded it and it works with `0.6.9`.

Answer (score 1):

For a version of Flutter less than 1.22 you need to specify this version in the `pubspec.yaml` file without the `^`:

```
auto_route: 0.6.7
```

Comment: I assume you meant `pubspec` not `pubspect` so I updated your answer accordingly.

Comment: I was testing the last version : 0.6.9 and it crashes everytime. 
0.6.7 seems to be ok though. Thank you !